# Bounty notice lost background color in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, ios-app

Recently, bounties' *values* have lost their background color here:

> [image]

This is how it used to look like in previous versions:

[image]

Comment: It's an issue in the latest official release (1.0.1), as well.

Comment: Still using old version (1.0.1.73) so took a screenshot. By the way, how can you update the beta channel version? The page we got in the email invitation isn't available for long weeks.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, *i have my ways...* uh, page has been back up for a while now. There have been a few updates. App doesn't see them though

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Are you seeing this issue on all questions with bounties? What device are you using?

Comment: @Arie, yes all questions with bounties. iPhone 5. I'm running iOS 8, but I've seen this since before it was released

Comment: And, uh, remind me again how do I search for questions with bounties in the app?

Comment: @mhlester there isn't a really easy way currently. I just look one up on the desktop and then search for it on the app.

Comment: @mhlester are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky affirmative in 1.0.1.86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILabel` seems to have some bugs when using a background color (specifically, the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` attribute). That was causing the bounty number value to render without its typical blue background. I have replaced the `UILabel` with a `UITextView`, and that's behaving much better.

It looks like this issue reproduces 100% of the time on iOS8, which is why we haven't been able to reproduce it until recently.

This will be fixed in the next beta update, version 1.1.0.118.